# Picklist dependent on 2 controlling picklist

Tags: dependent-picklist

I have 3 picklist in an object Test1, Test2, Test3 
1. Test2 is dependent on Test1 
2. Test3 is dependent on both.. Test1 and Test2

[image]

I want to have Test3 picklist showing values accordindly. i.e 
if U selected Test1 = First and Test2 = SA . I should be able to see "IST,ABC and PQR" in Test 3.

Is this possible???

Comment: If you can make third picklist dependent on second then i see possible chances of doing this

Comment: I tried doing that... If u create test3 dependent on test2. Its doesnt serve my purpose as u can see.. if i make IST dependent on CA... everytime i select CA from test2 i will be able to see IST. Wherin i dont want to see IST for CA where test1 values are FIRst and SECOND

Comment: thats where i see as impossibility for this requirement .With visualforce we can achieve this .

Comment: Ok will try with that... could you please help me out with sample code if any

Comment: 1-  Dependent picklist cannot have more than one controlling field
2- Controlling field can have multiple dependent picklists

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with standard [dependent picklists](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm). Instead, you would have to use Visualforce. Specifically, look into using [`<apex:selectOption>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_selectoption.htm) and populating it with a [`List<SelectOption>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_selectoption.htm) from the controller. You can then utilize an [`<apex:actionSupport>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) with the `event="onChange"`. You can then filter the results by rerendering the dependent picklists and filtering through Apex in the controller.

Comment: No problem @TestNS. I know it isn't ideal, but if this is the solution to your issue please mark this as the answer. It is important for the site to maintain a high answer rate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get an positive answer to this question?

After a long search on the internet i decided to make every value unique in the different picklists by adding a combination of letters and numbers at the end of each value (it's a little bit more work connecting the values) for users to pick from. For reporting i created additional formula fields in which i delete the extra letters and numbers and so creating a field with the right value names on each level.

Answer (score -2):

test3 is dependent on test2 as well as test1 so the only way to do it is with a custom controller because standard field dependency has only one-level of dependency.